Multiple Card Payments Using Dialog Flow Messenger
Does anyone know if it is possible to make more than one credit card payment using DF Messenger without starting a new chat session?  For example, if a person has multiple balances and wants to pay 2 specific balances out of 5 that they owe, can that be done without starting a new chat session.
Is there a way to refresh their current session as if they are starting over again as a new session?
Our current confiration only allows for one credit card payment.  If a person wants to make a second payment, they need to open a new chat session.
